# Bowing signs (?) in Lajos Montag's double bass method

Tags: double-bass, bowing

In volume II of Montag's double bass method, I found these signs above the staff which look like they should be bowing signs. My guesses for the arrows are either alternating down-bow and up-bow or whole bow. My guess for the sign that looks like a rotated rest would be "frog".

[image]

What do these signs mean? Are these standard signs or are these Montag's invention?  (They are not explained in that volume – maybe they *are* in volume I.)

Comment: Your guesses seem plausible to me, and I actually like the symbols. They should be standardized...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The are defined in the introduction. The arrows mean "full bow" and the other symbol (which is fairly standard) means "at the frog".

See the picture for the full set of symbols - apologies for the poor quality.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I agree that you are probably right.  The arrows mostly likely indicate using the whole bow.  I have been a professional double bass player for about 40 years and I have never come across those symbols.  They are not standard.  If the second symbol does mean play at the frog, it is slightly unusual since it is a pp passage and would be more comfortable further up the bow.

Comment: As "Guest" answered, these are edition-specific.  that is not at all unusual for various bowed-instrument study books.